# Compare Object and Long&Integer

Tags: java, object, compare

When I want to compare two variables(One type Object, one type Long), I found that cannot convert Object to Long, for example:

```
Object obj = 100;
Long l_num = 100L;

System.out.println(obj.equals((Object)l_num));    // print false
System.out.println(((Long)obj) == l_num);         // throw java.lang.ClassCastException Exception
```

Then I can only compare the two with `(obj.toString()).equals(l_num.toString())`, it returns true.

But, the result is different when I compare Integer with Object:
    
    `Object obj = 100;

    Integer i_num = 100;

    System.out.println(((Integer)obj) == i_num); // return true
    System.out.println(obj.equals(i_num));       // return true
    System.out.println((obj.toString()).equals(i_num.toString()));  // return true`

Is there someone kindly tell me why two results are different and is there any method better to compare Object with Long ?

If it's a meaningful question you think, let's talk about it. Thanks.

Comment: Consider what you are comparing and trying to cast to, `100` vs `100L`.

Comment: What do you think this `(obj.toString()).equals(l_num.toString())` does?

Comment: I didn't see anything weird happens here -_-

Answer (score 0):

`Long` and `Integer` are different types. you compared objects of  different types.

100 is `int`. So it is boxed to `Integer`. So obj and i_num can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Its preety straight forward -

```
Object obj = 100;
```

This 100 is an integer and `Object obj` hold that integer reference, you can make sure by `System.out.println(obj.getClass());` which prints `class java.lang.Integer`. And It is a example of [auto boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) -

```
System.out.println(((Long)obj) == l_num);
```

`(Long)Obj` throws the `ClassCastException` as it is trying to cast `Integer` object to `Long` object which is invalid.

write form would be -

```
System.out.println(((Long)((Integer)obj).longValue()) == l_num); // it return true
```

Comment: Thx, the matter is the real type of obj.

Comment: can you give a example